# Heroku Postgres configure data center location

Tags: postgresql, heroku

My understanding is that Heroku Postgres runs on top of AWS. Is it possible to configure which datacenter your database is running in? I'm also wondering if the database files are stored on an encrypted filesystem.

Comment: Heroku's site is not very informative, what is the best venue for asking/finding answers to questions like these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku runs out of Amazon US-East - once you've add a postgres db to your app `heroku config` will give you the database connection URL which you would be able to tracert on to see where it is

Comment: It's also in the DNS name of the instance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Heroku runs on AWS. But you are not able to specify which datacenter to run your database. For encryption look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html.

Comment: It's often better to do crypto application-side. If you use `pgcrypto` then your secret keys can be exposed in your database logs, captured by someone who's broken into the VM, viewed by misbehaving staff with access to the box, etc. If your data storage never sees the crypto keys used to decrypt the data it's storing, even transiently, then you've got stronger protection if the storage is compromised.

Comment: @Craig -- Not being able to index/query the data is a no go.

Comment: @limscoder If you can usefully index encrypted data that means you've got the decryption key stored in the database. It can be compromised by simply dumping the database or finding a leaked backup. Such encryption is nearly pointless. The only way you can really index encrypted data is by extracting the parts of interest and salting and hashing them for storage in an indexed column.When you're looking for them you hash the input with the same algorithm and same salt. This allows useful indexing for approximate equality but not sorting and collation. Even for equality uniqueness isn't assured.

Comment: @limscoder Encrypting data while preserving the ability to compare for equality or order is a very hard problem with a huge amount of research around it. Even something that sounds easy like saying 'are these two encrypted passages of text equal' is hard because of things like decomposed vs precomposed unicode pairs causing the 'same' text to be a different byte sequence and thus produce a totally different encrypted result.